# How should I connect this new ceiling light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling, light-fixture, light

[image]

[image]

I purchased a light fixture and the wires attached to the fixture are white, black and green.  The junction box where I am planning to install the light was unused and therefore capped.  When I removed the cap I came across the following wires:
- 2 x white bundles 
- 1 x black bundle 
- 1 x orange bundle
- 1 x green bundle
- 1 x single pink wire

How should I connect the light fixture?

Here's some context.  the ceiling fixture would be controlled by a switch on the room, HOWEVER, it would/should also be also be connected to a master all-off switch by the front entrance.  If this power-off switch is in the off position all light switches can't turn on.

Update:  I opened up the room switch and there's only one pink/red wire attached to it.

Comment: Welcome to diy.SE! Is the box already connected to the switches as you desire? What, if anything, was in the box previously?

Comment: Thanks! It was an unused junction box and therefore it was just covered with a ceiling cap. And yes, it's already connected to the switches.

Comment: Open the switch that is supposed to control this fixture and see what color wires are connected to the switch. (Not the master switch, the room switch).  And edit that into your question.  After it's hooked up then you can just test and I bet the master will just work.  My guess is you want red and white in the box pictured here, but tell us what's connected to the switch.

Comment: Where on this planet are you?

Comment: I am located in Toronto, Ontario, Canada.  I ran out of time today to try and install the light fixture, so will try again tomorrow.  I'll post an update then.  Thanks all!

Comment: @Tyson - I decided to open the room switch that is supposed to control the light and it only has a pink/red wire attached to it.  Does that mean I should connect white(fixture) to white (both wires in junction box), black (fixture) to red (junction box) and green to green?

Comment: That's how I see it =]

Comment: Can you get us a photo looking deeper into the box?  We need to see which wires are paired up....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I will take another photo with the plate off when I'm back from work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who provided advice.  I was able to get the light working properly.  I had to connect the fixture's:

- Black wire to the junction box pink/red wire
- White wire to white wire
- Green wire to green wire

Comment: Please accept your answer (or one of the others), and upvote any that were helpful. Stack Exchange has a protocol for this sort of thing.

Comment: Which bundle of white wires did you hook it to?

Comment: Answering your own question is cool here.  If you choose best answer you might even get some rep.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify which one of those is your switch leg (you have test equipment, right?). It sounds like you're on the right track. It's a switched-switch leg, so I'd *assume* then, that the yellow is the main switch leg, and the red is the local switch leg.

TL;DR; *don't care if I burn my house down*: hook on to the white and the red, and try it. I'd assume the black is 'always power'. And I'd *assume* every wire in that box is OK to share with the white neutral (so, try the yellow if you have to).

This answer *makes a lot of assumptions* that the OP will have to be willing to take responsibility for (and that Canadian electric color schemes largely adhere to the ones in the US).

---

I just noticed that **you may have two separate neutrals there**. This may require a little bit more of a sit-down than I thought... Pull all the wires out more (away from each other) and take another picture, if someone doesn't come around with a better answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mazura.  I've added a new photo to better reflect what cables are in the junction box.

Comment: Canadian rules require that green, green/white or bare be ground, white or gray be neutral, and any other color can be any kind of hot, except orange for 3-phase wild-leg.  In multiconductor cable (which I bet this is not), white wires can be marked a color to make them hots.